# Do the Vipers in the Re imagined Battlestar Galactica have turbos?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

I'm trying to recall if we ever see the Viper pilots in the re-imagined series hit a "Turbo" button like they did in the Original Series.
I recall seeing them do manoeuvres similar to "Full Breaking Flaps" (which doesn't actually make sense in space) but not Turbos.

Comment: _"which doesn't actually make sense in space"_ Sure it does.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Using flaps in space? How? (Not that BSG, cool as its space aesthetics are, is particularly worried about depicting realistic space battles. Its only nods to realism were the lack of sound and the use of projectile-based weapons)

Comment: @AndresF.: They're not air brakes. They're jets. The manoeuvres make perfect sense when you realise that.

Comment: I did figure they were really jets of some sort and not actually flaps, just used old terminology similar to referring to CD's or Digital downloads as Albums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.**

I specifically remember in Seasons 3's episode ["*Exodus Part 2*"](http://galactica.wikia.com/wiki/Exodus,_Part_II) where [Kat](http://galactica.wikia.com/wiki/Louanne_%22Kat%22_Katraine), after luring Cylons away, tells other Vipers and Raptors in her squadron to

> Kick in the Turbos! Let's get the hell out of here.

There probably are more examples, but that's the one I remember off the top of my head.

I'm trying to find a good picture of a Viper cockpit, but I just can't find one where you can read the buttons.

Comment: This site seemed to have the most information about the cockpit:
[link](http://www.galactiguise.com/welcome/sets/viper-mkii/viper-mk-ii-cockpit/)

Comment: @BrentKnorr personally, I was looking at the Viper Mk VII recreation in one of the Freespace 2 mods (which are highly accurate btw) and the prop auction pictures. Turbo is most likely activated by a pedal press, and not a button, in this one, and that's maybe why I didn't find anything